# spring-security samples saml2login error Metadata not found

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0, sample, simplesamlphp

I have been unable to get the saml2login sample to run.
Currently when attempting to run I get redirected to simplesaml-for-spring-saml.cfapps.io but I'm getting an error

```
 Metadata not found

 Unable to locate metadata for 'http://localhost:8080/saml2/service-provider-metadata/simplesamlphp'
 This is most likely a configuration problem on either the service provider or identity provider.
```

Here is the debug section

```
 SimpleSAML\Error\MetadataNotFound: METADATANOTFOUND('%ENTITYID%' => '\'http://localhost:8080/saml2/service-provider-metadata/simplesamlphp\'')

Backtrace:
 3 lib/SimpleSAML/Metadata/MetaDataStorageHandler.php:302 (SimpleSAML\Metadata\MetaDataStorageHandler::getMetaData)
 2 lib/SimpleSAML/Metadata/MetaDataStorageHandler.php:322 (SimpleSAML\Metadata\MetaDataStorageHandler::getMetaDataConfig)
 1 modules/saml/lib/IdP/SAML2.php:357 (SimpleSAML\Module\saml\IdP\SAML2::receiveAuthnRequest)
 0 www/saml2/idp/SSOService.php:21 (N/A)
```

Any clues what could be wrong?

Comment: Hi jay,  I'm facing this issue as well. Have you fixed this issue?

Comment: Hi Chi,
I was never able to get the sample working.  
I moved on and was able to get my code working with a "real" IDP.  
I believe the issue was on the simplesamlphp side, specifically with the conifguration used by the spring sample.